# Setting an image to coredata

Tags: ios, swift, core-data

I have a list of tableviewcells loaded. And beside each of those cells is an 'Add To favorite' button. When that 'Add To favorite' is clicked the image on it will change and that changed image should be stored into coredata so that when the app is run again I can know which cell was favorited. For that this is what has been tried...

```
        func favoriteBtnTapped(cell: HistoryTableViewCell) {

            if segmentControl.selectedSegmentIndex == 2 {
                favBtnTapFlag = true
                if let indexPath = tableview?.indexPath(for: cell) {

                    let myFavMsg = messages1[indexPath.row]
                    let likedMsg = myFavMsg.historyData


                    guard let appDelegate = UIApplication.shared.delegate as? AppDelegate else {
                        return
                    }
                    let managedContext = appDelegate.persistentContainer.viewContext

                    let entity = NSEntityDescription.entity(forEntityName: "FavoritedMessages", in: managedContext)

                    let category = NSManagedObject(entity: entity!, insertInto: managedContext)

                    category.setValue(likedMsg, forKeyPath: "favData")


//New image is set on the cell and it is saved to coredata here...                    
                    cell.favoriteButton.setImage(UIImage(named: "pin"), for: .normal)
    let imageData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation((cell.favoriteButton.imageView?.image)!, 1)

                    category.setValue(imageData, forKey: "favImage")
                    do {

                        try managedContext.save()
                      self.favMessages.append(category as! FavoritedMessages)


                    } catch let error as NSError {
                        print("Could not save. \(error), \(error.userInfo)")
                    }
                }
            }
```

And it is fetched in `viewWillAppear` like so...

```
override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillAppear(animated)

    guard let appDelegate =
        UIApplication.shared.delegate as? AppDelegate else {
            return
    }

    let managedContext =
        appDelegate.persistentContainer.viewContext

    let fetchRequest =
        NSFetchRequest<NSManagedObject>(entityName: "Messages")

    let fetchRequest1 = NSFetchRequest<NSManagedObject>(entityName: "FavoritedMessages")

    do {
        messages1 = try managedContext.fetch(fetchRequest as! NSFetchRequest<NSFetchRequestResult>) as! [Messages]

        favMessages = try managedContext.fetch(fetchRequest1 as! NSFetchRequest<NSFetchRequestResult>) as! [FavoritedMessages]

        for result in favMessages as [FavoritedMessages] {

            if let imageData = result.value(forKey: "favImage") as? NSData {
                if let image = UIImage(data:imageData as Data) as? UIImage {
                   favoritedImage.image = image 

                }
            }
        }

        tableview.reloadData()
    } catch let error as NSError {
        print("Could not fetch. \(error), \(error.userInfo)")
   }}
```

Here `favoritedImage.image = image` I'm trying to assign the fetched image to an imageview variable and then assign it at cellForRow. But how that can be done I'm not sure...

Comment: As it seems you have the pin image in your app, why do you save the image in CoreData?

Comment: In case I close the app & run it again I want to persist that image so that I can know which cell was favorited..

Comment: Save an image in document directory and save it’s path to core data. When required then get image for same path.

Comment: Agreed. But even in that case after fetching the path from the viewwillAppear, I will have to assign it to the appropriate cell right..? Even in my case I have fetched the image but how it can be assigned to the proper cell that I'm not sure..

Comment: @Jacky Saving the name is enough for the example given above.

Answer (score 1):

You should not save image in coredata.

Save the model with favourite_status as 1. (0 => unfavourited and 1 => favourited ) in coredata. (Basically boolean value)
Load the image from app bundle based on favourite_status.

When loading cells also use favourite_status to load image.

/// Edited

```
func favoriteBtnTapped(cell: HistoryTableViewCell) {

     //1. Get Entity from datasource(Array) using indexpath.row
     //2. Favorite the entity by setting favaorite_status = 1  
     //3. Save to coredata also
     //4. Reload Table view 

}


func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

     //1. Get Entity from datasource(Array) using indexpath= Array
     //2. Set cell image based on favaorite_status. Use UIImage.init(name:””) (if favaorite_status  == 0, imagename will be different)

}
```